# Why do people ask on the board and card games site about chess?

Tags: discussion

There is a site about chess an one about 
Board & Card Games.
I keep seeing questions about chess on the 
Board & Card Games site.
*The problem is it brakes the topic.
2 of 2 things need to happen.

1) Whoever reads this, move your chess posts and go around giving people this important advice
           2) Make it clear!

Comment: Sorry. What do you think the problem is? Please expand.

Comment: @Andrew How can this be a dupe of my question, when my question is predicated on the answer to this one?

Comment: @DonielF both questions specifically ask if chess questions should be moved to the chess se as off topic here. Your question is of better quality actually asking if they should be considered off topic and moved, while this 'question' is more a statement saying we should.

Answer (score 8):

People asking about Chess on *Board & Card Games* is not a problem for *Board & Card Games*. It doesn't ***break*** anything, Chess is a Board Game and is therefore on topic.

As to why people ask about Chess on *Board & Card Games* when *Chess* would seem the more obvious place, the answer is **they don't**. Not much anyway, looking at the chess tag there have only been 8 questions this year.

Comment: Then I've got to say, some posts aren't in that tag.